# How to bake refraction/transmission as seen from a specific camera viewpoint?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, osl

I'm trying to adapt the OSL script from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/112099), which allows baking of reflections as seen from a specific direction, defined as FakeCamPos:

```
shader osl_reflection_normal(
  vector FakeCamPos = 10,
  int IsCameraRay = 1,
  output normal ReflNormal = N)
{
    if (IsCameraRay)
    {
        // Normal pointing from FakeCamPos to here
        normal fakeCamNormal = normalize(P - FakeCamPos);

        // Reflect fakeCamNormal across the surface
        normal fakeReflection = reflect(fakeCamNormal, N);

        // For some reason I points towards the camera? Otherwise we'd use -I
        normal incidenceNormal = normalize(I);

        // The average of the incidence normal and the fake reflection normal gives us a normal that reflects one to the other.
        ReflNormal = normalize(fakeReflection + incidenceNormal);
    }
}
```

This works great for reflections, but not refraction. Is it possible? What would be the correct calculation to achieve this?